# Query in codeigniter view very slow

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have this query inside a codeigniter view and it takes about 10 minutes to load the data. If I remove the second select it loads pretty normally.

Could anyone see any reason to cause this?

Is there anything I can do here to improve the execution time and therefore increase my page load?

My code is as follows:

```
   <tbody>
                    <?php 
//$this->db->select('teacher.*,teacher_attendance.*');

$this->db->select('teacher.teacher_id,teacher.name,teacher_attendance.*');                    

$this->db->from('teacher_attendance');
$this->db->where ('timestamp', $timestamp);
$this->db->group_by('teacher.teacher_id');
$this->db->join('teacher', 'teacher.teacher_id = teacher_attendance.teacher_id', 'left'); 
//$this->db->limit(50);
$teachers   =$this->db->get()->result_array();

                                   foreach($teachers as $row){

                               ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $row['teacher_id'];?></td>
                            <td><img src="<?php //echo $this->crud_model->get_image_url('teacher',$row['teacher_id']);?>" class="img-circle" width="30" /></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['name'];?></td>

                            <td>

                           <select id="selected1" class="sele1 form-control selectboxit" name="status_<?php echo $row['attendance_id']; ?>">
                                    <option value="0" <?php if ($row['status'] == 0) echo 'selected'; ?>><?php echo get_phrase('undefined'); ?></option>
                                    <option value="1" <?php if ($row['status'] == 1) echo 'selected'; ?>><?php echo get_phrase('present'); ?></option>
                                    <option value="2" <?php if ($row['status'] == 2) echo 'selected'; ?>><?php echo get_phrase('absent'); ?></option>
                                </select>

                                 <!--    <input type="radio" name="status_<?php echo $row['attendance_id']; ?>" value="1"  <?php if ($row['status'] == 1) echo 'checked'; ?>/>
    &nbsp;
    <input type="radio" name="status_<?php echo $row['attendance_id']; ?>" value="2"  <?php if ($row['status'] == 2) echo 'checked'; ?> />
                          -->  
                            </td>
      <td>

      <select class="form-control selectboxit" name="leave_status<?php echo $row['attendance_id']; ?>">
                                    <option value="0" <?php if ($row['leave_status'] == 0) echo 'selected'; ?>><?php echo get_phrase('undefined'); ?></option>
                                    <option value="1" <?php if ($row['leave_status'] == 1) echo 'selected'; ?>><?php echo get_phrase('CASUAL'); ?></option>
                                    <option value="2" <?php if ($row['leave_status'] == 2) echo 'selected'; ?>><?php echo get_phrase('MEDICAL'); ?></option>
                                    <option value="3" <?php if ($row['leave_status'] == 3) echo 'selected'; ?>><?php echo get_phrase('DUTY'); ?></option>
                                    <option value="4" <?php if ($row['leave_status'] == 4) echo 'selected'; ?>><?php echo get_phrase('HALF DAY'); ?></option>
                                    <option value="5" <?php if ($row['leave_status'] == 5) echo 'selected'; ?>><?php echo get_phrase('OTHER'); ?></option>
                                    <option value="6" <?php if ($row['leave_status'] == 6) echo 'selected'; ?>><?php echo get_phrase('LATE'); ?></option>
                                    <option value="7" <?php if ($row['leave_status'] == 7) echo 'selected'; ?>><?php echo get_phrase('SHORT'); ?></option>

                                </select>
```

Comment: why are you writting query in view? should go conttroller then model and then return back.

Comment: You are not following MVC pattern.

Comment: When you say `the second select` you mean the HTML `<select>` tag? Can you share the code of `get_phrase()`?

Comment: yes i meant  <select> tag get_phrase() is something like an echo

Comment: First of all, you should write your queries in model, please keep it in your mind. To debug it, please add following code and tell me the output: 

`$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);`

Answer (score 0):

Remove `*` from the query and put only required colums. It will improve your query execution time. And also add index on table column on which you are using `WHERE` clause like `timestamp`, `teacher_id`, etc.

It will improve your query performance as fast as required.